# how to display multiple panels within one panel?

Tags: c#

I have main Panel. And main panel have 3 panels.
main panel contains 3 buttons.

i want to show on that button click show that particular panel within main panel.

[image]

Comment: We are not a coding service. We help fellow programmers with problems. So what *is* your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why don't you use a tab control

Comment: Sounds like you need a tab panel, did you look?

Comment: This would seem to me to be better suited to a tab panel, but if you want to go down this route can you let us know whether this is windows forms or WPF?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - To code what you described, why not, well, just do it??? Each button must Hide a few Panels and Show one Panel. Not hard at all!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you, you want to create different page's on one form. There is controller for this the Tab control : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using panels I recommend using a [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx). Have a look at this code snippet

```
        private void FirstPanelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyTabControl.SelectedTab = MyTabControl.TabPages[0];
        }
```